# Join in sql and repeated column

Tags: sql, join

How does join operation in sql repeat column in the resulted table?
Can we have repeated column or duplicated column name in one table? Or resulted table doesn't add to database table?

Comment: You can have repeated columns in join operation if you are using "Select *" or "Select table1.coulm1, tabl2.column1", so your resulted table will have the same column1 column1 in the resulted table. 
You can't have duplicate column name in same table.

Comment: Your question is not clear, please rephrase, expand or provide an example to clarify.

Answer (score 0):

Yes - you can have duplicated column names in the returned result set.

But if you had run your own [test](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9eecb7d/56965), you would have discovered that yourself.